# Pass a string into a Javascript function all in PHP - How to escape correctly?

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, quote

I have the following code:

```
echo '
    <td>    
        <input type="button" name="delete" value="X" onclick="clearSelection(this.form, '.$type.');this.form.submit();" />
    </td>'
;
```

The problem is that I cannot pass a string to the `clearSelection()` Javascript function, because `$type` needs to be in parentheses.

I tried it with backslash, u0222, multiple quotes and so on but nothing brought me to the solution.

**Solution:**

```
$type = json_escape_string($type);
$raw_text = "clearSelection(this.form, $type); this.form.submit();";
$escaped_text = htmlspecialchars($raw_text);
echo '<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="X" onclick="'.$escaped_text.'" /></td>';

function json_escape_string($str){
    $str = strtr($str, array('\\'=>'\\\\',"'"=>"\\'",'"'=>'\\"',"\r"=>'\\r',"\n"=>'\\n','</'=>'<\/'));
    return "'".$str."'";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it first:

```
$escaped_text = HtmlSpecialChars(json_encode($raw_text));
```

`json_encode()` turns it into a valid JS string, then `HtmlSpecialChars()` escapes it for use within an HTML attribute.

If you have an old version of PHP without json_encode(), use this instead:

```
$escaped_text = HtmlSpecialChars(json_escape_string($raw_text));

function json_escape_string($str){
    $str = strtr($str, array('\\'=>'\\\\',"'"=>"\\'",'"'=>'\\"',"\r"=>'\\r',"\n"=>'\\n','</'=>'<\/'));
    return "'".$str."'";
}
```

For your particular variables:

```
$escaped_type = HtmlSpecialChars(json_escape_string($type));
echo '<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="X" onclick="clearSelection(this.form, '.$escaped_type.'); this.form.submit();" /></td>';
```

Comment: What is if `json_encode()` isn't available? `Call to undefined function json_encode()`. PHP v. 5.2.9. OK, it seems that it would work without `json_encode()`.

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative function

Comment: If I use your function I get `'clearSelection(this.form, \'products\'); this.form.submit();'` in the onclick attribute (`onlick=""`). And that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should only be escaping `$type`!